# Handling error whiile extracting files using 7 zip through powershell command

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I am trying to extract a file using 7 zip and powershell command line. File is extracting with no issues but the 7zip throws error (Missing volume : sample.ZIP). I looks for zip file, still it extracts file. I want to suppress that error or I want to handle that error.

This is not a non terminating error. I also tried the below approach.

```
try {
    $ExtractedFile = Get-ChildItem D:\test\ | % {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" "e" D:\test\sample.z0004} -ErrorAction Stop
    write-host "ExtractedFile(s): $ExtractedFile"
} catch {
    Write-Host $error[0]
} finally {
```

Filename to be extracted: `sample.z0004`

I get the error:

> Missing volume : sample.ZIP

Can anyone suggest how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a lot of metadata is stored in the root Zip file (sample.zip). You took 1 part of archive, which luckily for you contains entire files you need, but it could be otherwise for other archives and you will not be able to extract anything. So the error is totally valid. If you still want to suppress error, you can enclose your code with `$ErrorActionPreference` and optionally add `Out-Null`, like this:

```
   $ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
   $ExtractedFile = Get-ChildItem D:\test\ | % {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" "e" D:\test\sample.z0004} 
   write-host "ExtractedFile(s): $ExtractedFile"
   $ErrorActionPreference= 'Stop'
```

Comment: This didn't make any changes. Also, I used -ErrorAction Continue/Stop/SilentlyContinue but it says "Unknown switch: -ErrorAction"

Comment: I tried it, not in cycle, but for a single file and had no errors. And `-ErrorAction` switch is indeed no allowed. You can remove the last line, maybe it will help, but then you will not see any errors in this script at all